# i have multi language website contain arabic & english but if the link is public/en i want to hide English in

Tags: laravel, localization

```
@foreach(LaravelLocalization::getSupportedLocales() as $localeCode => $properties)
                                     <a class="forex" rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ $localeCode }}" href="{{ LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL($localeCode, [], false) }}">
            {{ $properties['native'] }}
        </a>

                              @endforeach
```

i want to hide English in

Comment: Do you have any code?

Comment: @foreach(LaravelLocalization::getSupportedLocales() as $localeCode => $properties)
                                         <a class="forex" rel="alternate" hreflang="{{ $localeCode }}" href="{{ LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL($localeCode, [], false) }}">
                {{ $properties['native'] }}
            </a>
            
                                  @endforeach

Comment: Please put your code in original question inside code block so it's readable. You are more likely to get an answer.

Comment: i put it to the question can i find the answer please ?

Comment: Just write a `if` inside your loop, or write a method wrapping `LaravelLocalization::getSupportedLocales()` that removes the locale in pure PHP code